# How to "getStackTrace()" in old version of Java 1.3.1 (MXExeption)

Tags: java, exception, maximo

I'm developing using an older Java version which has no `getStackTrace()` method. There is a `printStackTrace` method but it's not printing where I want it.

Is there a way to extract the full contents of `Exception ex` (ex in this case, and a MXExeption)?

Cast to string array or something?

Comment: Which version exactly?

Comment: According to the Javadocs, `getStackTrace()` was introduced in Java 1.4. That came out in 2002.  Why are you still using a Java platform that was superceded 12 years ago??

Comment: Hold on, let me check exactly which version

Comment: It's Java version 1.3.1

Answer (score 3):

Maybe that helps:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
ex.printStackTrace(pw);
String stacktrace = sw.getBuffer().toString();
```

Comment: And for Thread.getStackTrace `try { throw new E(); } catch (E e)`

Comment: Exception.getStackTrace() exists since 1.4 so I guess he uses a java version prior to 1.4. Thread.getStackTrace() exists since 1.5 (says javadoc).

Comment: Will try this and let you know how it works (using Java 1.3.1)